# How can I know which docker will restart after docker daemon restarts

Tags: docker, containers

I need to bind specific host port '5000' to container, and I use 'netstat -ntlap grep 5000' command to check host port whether is available. If the port is available, I will add 'insecure-registry' option to docker conf file, and then restart docker daemon. However, some containers stop before will restart, and may use '5000' port, and causes my new container start fail. How can I know which container will restart after docker daemon restarts? or just find out which  container started with '--restart=always'  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of docker ps -aq (which shows you all containers, even those non-running), give them to xargs and let a customized format of docker inspect return you the results:

```
$ docker ps -aq | xargs docker inspect --format '{{.Name}} Restart: {{ .HostConfig.RestartPolicy.Name }}'
/goofy_kirch Restart: 
/condescending_almeida Restart: 
/modest_nobel Restart: 
/ecstatic_swirles Restart: 
/angry_ritchie Restart: 
/hungry_wright Restart: 
/suspicious_lichterman Restart: 
/compassionate_ptolemy Restart: 
/modest_leakey Restart: always
```

Answer (score 2):

or another (similar) way

`docker inspect --format '{{.Name}} Restart: {{ .HostConfig.RestartPolicy.Name }}' $(docker ps -aq)`